# Is the constructor called immediately for an array of objects as a member of the class?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

```
class gene{
    int ind;

    gene() {
        ind = 0;
    }
}

class network {
    gene g[10];
}

main() {
    network n;
}
```

Should I call the constuctor for each object in the g array, or it will be called automatically?

e.g, should I change the network class as follows:

```
class network {
    gene g[10];

    network() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            g[i] = gene();
    }
}
```

Comment: If it wasn't already constructed, your change would be a disaster. You'd be calling 'operator=' on an unconstructed object.

Comment: I'm not trying to be snarky, but in the time it took you to ask the question, you could have tested it.

Comment: @Steve : Testing would only prove one compiler's behavior, which isn't necessarily what is guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @Steve you are 100% right. But I was so confused that I could not think of any thing.

Comment: @ildjarn - If you are using a non-standard compiler, it doesn't matter what the standard is.  It only matters what the compiler does.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: You should get familiar with *constructor initializer lists*: `gene::gene() : ind(0) { }`

Comment: @Steve : The point is that the compiler is allowed to go above and beyond what the standard requires. E.g. if `gene` were a POD type, the standard doesn't require that the code would value-initialize `gene::ind`, but many compilers do exactly this in debug mode. This does not make those compilers non-standard, it merely makes the compiler's observable behavior unreliable.

Comment: @ildjarn - My point is, you have to dance with the one you brought to the dance.

Comment: @Steve : Or, ask what the behavior _guaranteed_ by the standard is. Which is what this question is. Which is why the question is legitimate. ;-]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case, because `gene` has a non-trivial default constructor, each element of the array will be default-constructed for you. I.e., no, your change is unnecessary.

In the circumstance that your array's underlying type is a POD type, you *will* need to initialize the elements manually. However, the way you're doing it is not ideal; you would want to use *value-initialization* instead:

```
class network {
    somePodType x[10];
public:
    network() : x() { }
};
```